# Subtract datetime columns of alternate rows in a for loop using python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, datetime

I have two csv columns in a csv file as follows:

```
2019-03-22 12:51:04 2019-03-22 12:52:37
2019-03-22 12:50:38 2019-03-22 12:50:57
```

I want to subtract this 2019-03-22 12:50:57 from this 2019-03-22 12:51:04 that is they are both in different columns and different rows.
How do we do that in python when I have almost 300 rows and I want to loop over all the rows?

Comment: how would it work for the rest of the dataframe. would you always subtract in the same pattern ? basically time1, date1 - time2, date2[1 position lagged] ?

Comment: @rpm787 yes it will go in the same pattern for rest of df

Comment: Just added a solution below. Basically, I combined col1, col2 to create a fulltimedate1 column and col3, col4  to create a fulltimedate2 column. Then do fulltimedate1 - fulltimedate2(shifted by -1 i.e. 1 step up)

Comment: @rpm787 that is where the problem lies , I don't know pandas . I want to do it in simple python . Something like we iterate over a 2D array to access cell and do the subtraction

Comment: Here I read csv using csv reader then I need to be able to do it without using pandas, I found most of the solutions are in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried doing it here. This works for me even though it's not too pretty.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

data = [['2019-03-22', '12:51:04','2019-03-22', '12:52:37'], ['2019-03-22', '12:50:38', '2019-03-22', '12:50:57']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['d1','t1', 'd2', 't2' ])

def timestamp_(row, colNum):
    if colNum == 1:
        fulldate = time.mktime(time.strptime(row['d1']+ " " + row['t1'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    elif colNum == 2:
        fulldate = time.mktime(time.strptime(row['d2']+ " " + row['t2'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    return fulldate

df['fulltime1'] = df.apply(timestamp_, colNum=1, axis=1)
df['fulltime2'] = df.apply(timestamp_, colNum=2, axis=1)

df['timediff'] = df['fulltime1'] - df['fulltime2'].shift(-1)
#Answer will be in seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `datetime` and `csv`, no `pandas` necessary:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import re

row = []

with open('dates.csv', newline='\n') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')

    for i, line in enumerate(reader):


        dt1 = datetime.strptime(' '.join(line[0:2]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        dt2 = datetime.strptime(' '.join(line[2:4]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        row.append([dt1, dt2])

# row1column2 - row2column3 ?
row1column2 = row[0][1]
row2column3 = row[1][1] # ?

result = row1column2 - row2column3

print(result)
```

output:

```
0:01:40
```

Might improve parsing the dates out of each line more efficiently, but so far this may suit your needs.

Comment: No they are sub tracting the columns from same row not from different row see my question , I have asked that I have to subtract from row1column2- row2column3 something like this

Comment: yes of course you can do that, just adjust the row indices

Comment: adjusting the indices doesn't change rows it changes columns and stays in the same row . Can you show me how you would do it

Comment: @0decimal0 you want to subtract from row1column2- row2column3, but your csv has only two csv columns, where is column3?

Comment: what is the delimiter/cell separator character in your `csv` file? i mean what character separates the columns? spaces? and how many columns? your question says 2 columns, but your comment suggests 3 or more columns?

Comment: that's how I would do it